# How do I take a list of numbers and split them into 2 categories?

Tags: r

How do I take a numeric vector and categorize them into 2 separate groups?
For example, I want to take the list of numbers and put all the numbers greater than 100 in one column and less than 100 in the other. How do I do this?

Comment: Try `split(vec, vec >100)`

Comment: Take care with language. "List" has a specific meaning in R, which I think is not what you mean by "list of numbers". It always helps to include some data and code so we can see exactly what you are doing. Also, putting groups of unequal length into columns is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a filter expression, to extract matching criteria.
Assuming a list X with values 1 to 199 you, you could filter anything below 10 like `X[(X < 10)]` or multiples of 3 `X[(X %% 3)]`

With this in mind the following code filters the list, storing the values, then generates a new data frame with the two sorted columns.

```
x <- 1:199
over_100 = x[(x > 100)]
less_100 = x[(x < 100)]
y <- data.frame(over_100, less_100)

y
```